# How can I make my chrome extension automatically scroll the webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I looked through the google chrome api and was unable to find anything on scrolling through a webpage. How would I proceed with making a google chrome extension that automatically scrolls down a webpage and specify where it stops scrolling?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the Chrome APIs, because this is covered by the web platform APIs themselves.

[`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) and friends will help. You'll need to execute them in a content script.

If you just need to scroll to a particular element, give it an ID and navigate to it: `http://example.com/#scrolltarget`

As to which logic you want to apply to scroll "automatically", it's not clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this chrome extension: https://github.com/misak113/drone.io-autoscroll